# Suppose that $X$ is a finite set, and is Hausdorff as a topological space. Show that $X$ is discrete (as a topological space).

Tags: general-topology

***Problem :*** Suppose that $X$ is a finite set, and is Hausdorff as a topological space. Show that $X$ is discrete (as a topological space).

***Thoughts:*** I'm not even quite sure what the question is asking. I know the definition of a discrete topology is that a set is open in $X$ if it is a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$, so then can't the discrete topology be applied to any set and so any $X$ is discrete? Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is enough to prove that every singleton is open. Fix $a$ and for every $b\neq a$ find a neighborhood $U_b$ of $a$ not containing $b$. Then consider $\bigcap _{b\neq a}U_b$.

Comment: The discrete topology can be applied to any set, but that's not what's happening here. Here all we know is that the space is Hausdorff, and you are supposed to _show_ that this means that the space is discrete. In general, Hausdorff is a weaker condition than discrete (e.g. $\Bbb R$ with standard topology is Hausdorff but not discrete). Your task is to show that when the space is finite, the notions of Hausdorff and discrete coincides.

Comment: @Arthur I think I am confused what a discrete topology means.

Comment: It means that all subsets are open.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, we know that singletons are closed. Therefore, all finite subsets of $X$ are closed (finite unions of closed sets are closed). Since all subsets of $X$ are finite, it follows that *every* subset of $X$ is closed. Using this it is not hard to see that every subset of $X$ is open.